# Given a particular vector $X$, find a non-zero square matrix $A$ such that $AX=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $X = \left[-7,2,-6\right]^T$, how would you find $A$ using $AX=0$?

Comment: There are _many_ of these matrices. So I suggest you just get started, guess a few entries (say, six entries to start), and solve for the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the columns of $A$ are $u$, $v$ and $w$, then
$$AX=-7u+2v-6w.$$
You can pick any columns so that the above sums to zero, such as $u=(2,2,2)$, $v=(1,1,1)$ and $w=(-2,-2,-2)$, thus

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&1&-2\\2&1&-2\\2&1&-2\end{pmatrix}$$
is a possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

Choose something really easy e.g.
$\begin{pmatrix}                                          
2&7&0 \\                                                  
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

So you need a $3×3$ matrix each of whose rows have dot product $0$ with the given vector.

How about $\begin {pmatrix}0&3&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$?

Answer (score 0):

The rows of the matrix must have dot product $0$ with $[ -7\; 2\; -6 ] ^T$.

To find such rows, you could take a vector not spanned by $[ -7 \;2 \;-6 ]$

and then take the cross product of that vector with $[ -7\; 2\;- 6 ]$,

but I can just eyeball and see that $[2 \;1 \;-2]$ has dot product $0$ with $[-7\;2\;-6]^T$,

so one answer is $\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 & -2 \\2 & 1 & -2\\2 & 1 & -2\end{pmatrix}.$